# Is the power set of the natural numbers countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Some explanations:**

A set S is [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) if there exists an injective function $f$ from $S$ to the natural numbers ($f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$).

$\{1,2,3,4\}, \mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$ are all countable.

$\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

The [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $\mathcal P(A) $ is defined as a set of all possible subsets of A, including the empty set and the whole set.

$\mathcal P (\{\})=\{\{\}\}, \mathcal P (\mathcal P(\{\}))=\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}\} $

$\mathcal P(\{1,2\})=\{\{\}, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

**My question is:**

Is $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ countable? How would an injective function $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ look like?

Comment: It isn't countable. To prove this, you can use diagonalization directly, or use the fact, which presumably has been proved by now, that the reals are uncountable.

Comment: This question has been asked before.

Comment: The cardinality of the power $\mathcal P (A)$ of any set A is always higher than the cardinality of a set A (Source: "Lineare Algebra", ISBN 978-3-528-66508-1, page 14)

Comment: As  a footnote to the answers already given, you should also see a useful result known variously as the Schroeder-Bernstein, Cantor-Bernstein, or Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein  theorem. Some books present the easy proof;  some others have the hard proof of it.

Comment: It's not countable, as provable by diagonal argument, but the set of all FINITE subsets, and even ordered sequences, of natural numbers, or even integers or rational numbers, is, which I first realized by using extended definitions of prime factorization as ordered sequences of exponents to first however-many primes, though there may be an easier proof.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[Cantor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) states that for any set $A$ there is no surjective function $A\to\mathcal P(A)$. With $A=\mathbb N$ this implies that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is not countable.

(But where on earth did you find those nice explanations of countability and power sets that didn't also tell you this?)

Comment: Those nice explanations of countability and power sets were written by myself. Thanks for the compliment ;-) I just wanted to make sure that everybody who reads this question knows what I'm talking about

Comment: Today I thought about this again and I am a little bit confused. The powerset $\mathcal{P}(A_n)$ with $A_n := \{1, ..., n\}$ is finite for every $n$. So can't I simply count up for every $A_n$ (so first $\mathcal{P}(A_1)$, then $\mathcal{P}(A_2)$, $\mathcal{P}(A_3)$, ...? Where does it break?

Comment: @moose: You're going to miss every subset of $\mathbb N$ that is not finite, such as the set of all even numbers.

Comment: Thank you! It's so obvious when you read it ... I ask because I have an application where I need (theoretically; it is a generator) every finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and this is something that bothered me.

Comment: @moose: Bonus hint: The binary representation of a natural number provides a nice enumeration of the finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: would this be true for the rationals and integers as well?

Answer (score 12):

Power set of natural numbers has the same cardinality with the real numbers. So, it is uncountable.

In order to be rigorous, [here's a proof of this.](http://legacy.earlham.edu/%7Epeters/writing/infapp.htm)

Comment: It might be useful to include a proof of this fact, or cite a source for it at least.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my favorite proof that
$$|\mathcal{P}(M)| > |M|, \quad\forall M.$$

### Proof

$$\big[\exists\phi:M \stackrel{\mathrm{on}}{\to}\mathcal{P}(M)\big]$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\Big[\big[A_{\not\phi} := \{m|m\in M, m\notin\phi(m)\}\big]\Rightarrow A_{\not\phi}\in\mathcal{P}(M)\Rightarrow\exists p\in M:\phi(p) = A_{\not\phi}\Big]$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\Big[\big[p\in A_{\not\phi}\Rightarrow p\notin A_{\not\phi}\big]\quad \mathrm{and}\quad\big[p\notin A_{\not\phi}\Rightarrow p\in A_{\not\phi}\big]\Big]$$
$$Q.E.D.$$

Comment: This is just the usual proof, which was linked to in the other (six year old!) answers.

Comment: Sorry for repeating. By the way, may be it is well known proof, but it does not imply it is usual. Rather the opposite. Sorry for not mathematical discussion.

Comment: It is the usual proof - do you know of any basic set theory texts which introduce the theorem using a different argument?

Comment: I liked the proof and it being done here was pretty enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

[Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) tells us that for every set $A$, there is no surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$. In particular, there is no surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, and so $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is not countable.* For completeness, I will give the standard proof of Cantor's Theorem here.

Suppose $f:A\to\mathcal P(A)$ is a function, and consider the set $B=\{x\in A:x\not\in f(x)\}$. We shall show that $B$ is not in the range of $f$, and so $f$ is not surjective. Suppose, to the contrary, that $B$ is in the range of $f$. Then, there is an $x_0\in A$ such that $f(x_0)=B$.

Now consider the question of whether $x_0$ is an element of $B$. If $x_0\in B$, then $x_0\not\in f(x_0)$, so $x_0\notin B$; contradiction. On the other hand, if $x_0\not\in B$, then $x\in f(x_0)$, so $x_0\in B$; contradiction. Therefore, $B$ is not in the range of $f$, and the proof is complete.

---

*This means that there is no injection from $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to $\mathbb N$ either, for if $f:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb N$ were an injection, then $f$ would have a left inverse, and such a left inverse would be a surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.