# Proof check: Set of bijections from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is not countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I've seen other answers to this question and wanted to take another approach to it. I'd appreciate some feedback:

Suppose said set was countable, then we can enumerate each bijection, say as $S:=\{f_n: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} | n\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{and } f_n \text{ is a bijection}\}$. Since each $f_n$ is bijective, can create the correspondence to its unique inverse:
$$f_n \longleftrightarrow f_n ^{-1}$$

Consider the set of bijective inverses, $S':=\{f^{-1}_{n}: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} | n\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{and } f^{-1}_{n} \text{ is the inverse of} f_n \}$. Then it must be that
$$S = S'$$,

otherwise, there is some inverse function $f_m^{-1}$ not in S, which would contradict the countability of $S$.

On the other hand, $S \subset S'$ means that for an arbitrary $n$, $f_n \in S'$, so there is some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$f_n(x) = f_m ^{-1} (x) $$
for each x. This means that,
$$f_m(f_n (x)) =x $$
So that $f_m$ is the inverse of $f_n$; but by construction of S', it must be that $m=n$. Since $n$ was arbitrary we have that each bijection is its own inverse, which means that for each $n$, $f_n=Id_{\mathbb{N}}$, the identity function on $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, $$S = \{Id_{\mathbb{N}}\}$$ a contradiction.

Comment: Where does your proof use the fact that these are bijections from $\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$? As far as I can tell your proof goes through unchanged if we consider the set of bijections from, say, $[1\ldots20]\mapsto[1\ldots20]$, but the result is obviously false there.

Comment: Yes, each $f_n$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Actually, I asked more specifically where the proof uses the fact that they're specifically bijections of the whole set $\mathbb{N}$, because if this proof were correct then it would seem to show that the set of bijections from $[1\ldots 20]$ to itself is also uncountable.

Comment: @HyperbolicCake In other words, what is it that goes wrong if we were to apply this kind of argument to bijections over a finite set instead?

Comment: @RushabhMehta The set definition $S=\{n\not\in\mathbb N\mid n\in f(n)^{-1}(0)\}$ seems uninterpretable. Perhaps you have some typos

Comment: The last part doesn't quite make sense. First, $f_m$ is the inverse of $f_n$ needs also $f_n(f_m(x))=x$. Also, a bijection which is its own inverse is not necessarily the identity.

Comment: @HyperbolicCake In fact, the set of bijections **that are their own inverse** is itself uncountable

Comment: @RushabhMehta Reading the definition literally, it says "the set of $n$ **not in $\Bbb N$** (that's the first issue) such that $n$ is **an element of the number** $[f(n)]^{-1}(0)$ (that's the second issue). It's not clear what that's supposed to mean

Comment: Just wanted to say I remember I saw an answer to this which was absolutely beautiful (I'm into analysis though). If you look it up on the site I'm sure you'll find that eventually. It uses that a non absolutely convergent series with terms going to zero can, up to some reordering, converge to any real number. So you take $\sum_i (-1)^{n_i} /n_i $ and depending on the permutation you can get any real number you want. There are much more direct proofs but this was so nice I couldn't resist to write it here.

Comment: @BenGrossmann A correct proof: Assume we already know that the set of binary sequences is uncountable (powerset proof). Let $S$ be the set of binary sequences, and $B$ the set of bijections. Then, consider the injection $f:S\to B$ defined as $$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)(n)=2\cdot n+x_n$$This shows that $B$ is uncountable

Comment: @RushabhMehta Apparently I had seen an old version. That said, $n \in f(n)^{-1}(0)$ should presumably be $n \neq f(n)^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @RushabhMehta But yes, your proof is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct some bijection like this, for all pairs of consecutive numbers, either let them unchanged (coded $0$) or swap them (coded $1$).

Example :

$\begin{array}{l:ll|ll|ll|ll|ll|l}n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&\cdots\\f(n)&0&1&3&2&4&5&6&7&9&8&\cdots\\\text{code}&&0&&1&&0&&0&&1&\cdots\end{array}$

You can see that $f$ is a bijection which is its own inverse since both identity and swaps over two elements are their own inverse.

This makes you last argument ($S=\{Id_N\}$) invalid.

It is also clear that any sequence of $0$ and $1$ uniquely defines such bijections, therefore there are $\#(\{0,1\}^\mathbb N)=2^{\aleph_0}$ such bijections, and consequently at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ bijections from $\mathbb N$ into itself, making it uncountable.

On the other hand there are less bijections from $\mathbb N$ into itself than simply functions from $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ whose cardinal is also $2^{\aleph_0}$ (see [Encode each $n_1,n_2,n_3,...∈N^N$ by an inﬁnite sequence of 0s and 1s with inﬁnitely many 0s, and give a proof that $N^N$ is equinumerous with $R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146599/399263)).
This time you have an injection so the number of bijection is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, and since we proved above it is also at least this, then it is equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks for taking the time to interpret my attempt!

Answer (score 0):

The step where you are wrong is this:

> So that $f_m$ is the inverse of $f_n$, but this is to say that $m=n$.

*Non sequitur!* If one bijection is the *inverse* of another, it does not follow that function and other (=inverse) function are equal.

Comment: True, but the construction of $S'$ is built on the correspondence between each function and its inverse, i.e. $f_n \longleftrightarrow f^{-1}_n $. In other words, the subscripts have to correspond between inverses.

Comment: You can't require both. Either you take $f_m ^{-1}$ such that $f_n (x) = f_m ^{-1} (x)$ or you choose to order $S'$ the same way as $S$. I mean, take $f_n \neq Id$ and you see that you can't have both on every $x$.

Comment: @tommy Presumably you mean $f_n \neq f_n^{-1}$, which is not equivalent to $f_n \neq Id$.

Comment: $S'$ corresponds to $S$ so they're ordered the same way and $S'$ inherits the countability by the correspondence.

Comment: Oh yeah of course, I'll edit that. EDIT: Can't edit a comment that old apparently. Oh well.

Comment: Overall, the conclusion is not that the function and inverse are the same, but that their indices are the same which tells you that each bijection ends up being its own inverse, a unique property that the identity function.

Comment: @HyperbolicCake Firstly, that's still not deducible from your proof, because you _can't_ guarantee that $S$ and $S'$ are ordered the same; all you can say is that for every $n$ there's some $m$ such that $f_n()^{-1}=f'_m()$. Secondly, there are plenty of bijections that are their own inverses; for instance, the bijection that swaps 1 and 2 and sends every other number to itself.

Comment: @HyperbolicCake As I said in an earlier comment: not only is it false that the property of "being it own inverse" is unique to the identity function, but there are actually uncountably many functions that have this property.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll answer here, not with the answer (I gave it in the comments under the question and your question has some duplicates on the site) but with an explanation of why your argument is wrong, which is far more instructive in my opinion.

You say: suppose the set of bijections $S$ is countable, so $S=\{ f_n \text{ bijections} \}$. Then map this set by sending $f_n$ to $g_n = f_n ^{-1}$ in $S'$. It's easy to see that $S=S'$. Now you say: given $f_n$, consider a $g_m$ such that:

$ f_n (x)= g_m (x) \text{ for every } x.$

But then you see that it must be $g_m = f_n$ BY DEFNITION. If two functions send the same elements in the same place they are equal. So by inverting you find $x=x$, which yeah it's true but meaningless. Your error is in thinking the functions in $S'$ as inverses, that's what put you off. If you wanted to use inverses, than you'd want a $f_m ^{-1}$ such that:

$$ f_m ^{-1} (x) = f_n (x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{N}.$$

But beware: this means that $f_m$ sends $f_n (x)$ to $x$, because the you want the inverse to do the reverse. So in the end $f_m= (f_n ^{-1})^{-1} = f_n$.