# How many injective functions are there in $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I was wondering what's the cardinality of $\{f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \mid f \text{ is injective}\}$? I know it's uncountable, but what 'type' of uncountable? Is it the same cardinality of all surjective functions over $\mathbb{N}$? What about of all bijective functions over $\mathbb{N}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The set of bijections has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (same as the power set, same as the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself). As that is contained in the set of injections, and in the set of surjections, the latter sets also have the same cardinality.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183513/742) for the cardinality of the set of all functions.

Comment: see my answer here for the set of bijections https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418195/399263

Comment: You can find some posts about the set of *bijections* on this site, such as "[Is symmetric group on natural numbers countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1321653)" and various [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1321653). And, naturally, you have $|\operatorname{Bij}(\mathbb N,\mathbb N)|\le |\operatorname{Inj}(\mathbb N,\mathbb N)| \le \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.