# Proof that the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ is not enumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to show that the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ is not enumerable. Can someone verify my proof below?

Proof: 
Let $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{N})$ be the set of all functions such that $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ 
Define $\Phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{N})$ and suppose by hypothesis $\Phi$ is surjective.
Let $A \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{N})$ be a set of functions such that $ g_{n}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{n\} \neq \Phi_{n}$.
Then, $A \neq \Phi $, $\Phi$ is not surjective by the Cantor's diagonal argument. Contradiction!

EDIT: $A \subset \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{N})$

Comment: $A\in\mathcal F(\mathbb N;\mathbb N)$ means that $A$ is a function. However, you call it a set of functions... Is $g_n$ the function sending each element of $\mathbb N$ to $n$? What is the relation between $g_n$ and $A$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "a set of functions such that $g_n\colon \mathbb{N}\to \{n\}$..."? I don't understand your notation.

Comment: EDIT: A \subset \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{N})

Comment: How would be a proof for the proposition?

Comment: Did you change the question from "Verify my proof" to "Give a proof"? Because the current version of the proof you suggest is difficult to save...

Comment: Your proof does not appear to be sound.  The third line is especially problematic.  I would be easier to proceed if you express $\mathcalF$ as the set of all sequences of natural numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your argument is salvageable, but there are definitely some issues.

On the second line, you want to say something along the lines of "Suppose that there exists a surjective function $\Phi: \mathbb N \mapsto \mathcal{F}(\mathbb N; \mathbb N)$." Using the word "define" is a little misleading in this context.

The third line of your proof does not make sense as written. It looks like you are trying to adapt the canonical proof of [Cantor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem), but you've adapted the method in a way that doesn't quite work. In this case, you want to define a *function* that cannot be in the range of $\Phi$. Trying to cook up some special *subset* of $\mathcal F(\mathbb N; \mathbb N)$ isn't helpful.

The idea of applying a "diagonalization argument" is a good one (forget about $A$). Define $g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by $$g(n)=\Phi(n)(n)+1.$$ Note that this makes sense, since $\Phi(n): \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ is a function for each $n$, so we can apply it to the natural number $n$. Also note that $g \neq \Phi(n)$ for any $n$: the values of $g$ and $\Phi(n)$ at $n$ differ. This contradicts surjectivity of $\Phi(n)$.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't get it. Could you explain more the function $g$ and $\Phi$

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte no problem. The function $\Phi$ is a surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal F(\mathbb N; \mathbb N)$, assumed to exist for a contradiction. This means that $\Phi(n): \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is a function for each $n$. We can consider $\Phi(n)(k) \in \mathbb N$ for each $k$; this is the value of the function $\Phi(n)$ at $k$. Now, we want to define $g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ so that $g \notin \Phi(\mathbb N)$. We do this by a "diagonalization" trick: defined $g$ by $g(n) = \Phi(n)(n)+1$, and for each $n$. Then $g$ and $\Phi(n)$ differ at a value (namely $n$).

Comment: Since $g$ differs from any $\Phi(n)$ at a value, $g$ is not equal to *any* element in the image of $\mathbb N$ under $\Phi$, which contradicts the surjectivity assumption.

Comment: Finally, I've got it. Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This proof based on the fact that [$\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ is not enumerable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86650/proof-that-the-power-set-of-mathbbn-is-uncountable-and-that-the-compositio) : 
Let $\varphi:\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to \mathcal F(\Bbb N,\Bbb N)$ defined by 
$\varphi(A)=\chi_A$ , $\varphi$ is injective and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is not enumerable, hence $\mathcal F(\Bbb N,\Bbb N)$ is not enumerable.

Comment: OP wrote: "Can someone verify my proof below?" He's not asking for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, then we can identify $f$ with the sequence of natural numbers $\langle a_1, a_2, \dots \rangle$, where $f(n) = a_n$.

If you define $\mathcal F$ as the set of all such sequences, then using diagonalization will be much more natural and clear.

Comment: @Guilherme D Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/141127/8271)